# Local diffeomorphism of Euclidean space is a global diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-topology

I am learning about the Legendre transform and found in Mac Lane's Geometrical Mechanics lecture notes (v1 p.54) the following inversion theorem:

> The Legendre transformation $\ v\in V\mapsto dL(v)\in V^*$ is invertible if and only if the Hessian matrix of $L$ is non singular at each point

where $L:V\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is a (Lagrangian) function (at a given point in space, V represents the tangent space). Looking further in the literature, there seem to be a distinction made between *regular* Lagrangians (Legendre transformation is locally invertible) and *hyperregular* (Legendre transformation is globally invertible). I assume the lecture notes overlooked this distinction.

Looking for a global inversion theorem, I found [a paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2316266) by W.B. Gordon in which he asserts that

> A $\mathcal{C}^1$ map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a diffeomorphism if and only if $f$ is proper and its Jacobian determinant never vanishes.

I am interested in the second proof, more topological. The paper first asserts that $f$ is onto then concludes that $f$ is a covering of a simply connected space, hence a global diffeomorphism.

It is not proved that $f$ is onto, which seems to use some basic degree theory. I am not very familiar with the degree of maps but I assume we want to prove that the degree is $\pm 1$ so that each point is in the image, according to the formula $\forall y\in\mathbb{R}^n, \operatorname{deg}f = \sum_{f(x)=y} \operatorname{deg}_x f$.

How can I prove that f is onto? Actually I'm not even sure how the degree of the map is defined (do we consider the continuous map between the one-point compactifications? Or maybe we consider the non-compactly supported de Rham top cohomology ?)

Assuming the theorem, it would then seem that a regular Lagrangian is hyperregular provided its associated Legendre transformation is proper.

Comment: Proper map with open nonempty image will be surjective.

Comment: $f(\mathbb R^n)$ is closed because $\mathbb R^n$ is closed and $f$ is closed (being proper).

$f(\mathbb R^n)$ is open by [Invariance of Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) because the Jacobian is nonzero at each point, so we are locally injective.

Since $\mathbb{R^n}$ is connected, if $f$ has nonempty image it must be surjective. This proof of course extends past $\mathbb{R}^n$ (e.g. to manifolds) since Invariance of Domain extends. I think we could actually extend this even further since Invariance of Domain is heavier hitting than we need here.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers, I totally forgot that the proper map will be closed. Please don't hesitate to post an answer so that I can accept it